# Is this a bug in date-fns library, converting a date to UTC format give me wrong time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, date-fns

So I use [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) to converting current date to UTC. This is my code :

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';


function currentDate() {
  return format(Date.now(), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ');
}
```

the output of this function is a date with this format : `2018-11-27T16:11:73+01:00`

As you can see in Time section, the seconds is 73 ( More then 60 ) `16:11:73` and this make a problem for my serverside code where I need to validate the user data, so obviously will fail when it want cast to date with this error : `Cast to date failed for value "2018-11-27T16:11:73+01:00" at path currentDate`

Any idea guys?

Comment: minutes = `mm`, seconds = `ss` lowercased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are providing is wrong.

- minutes = `mm`,
- seconds = `ss` 
  *(lowercased)*

See full list here: https://date-fns.org/v1.9.0/docs/format

`SS` is 1/100 of second